# Mapstruct dependency injection using componentModel = "spring" gives null object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, mapstruct

I am trying to inject a mapper object (class is TypeMapper) dependency using Spring as follows,

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        uses = {TypeMapper.class})
public interface AttachmentMapper {

  AttachmentMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(AttachmentMapper.class);

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(source = "type", target = "type") })
  AttachmentDTO toDTO(Attachment attachment);
}
```

Code for TypeMapper is as follows,

```
@Component
@Mapper
public abstract class TypeMapper {

  public abstract Type mapType(DtoType DtoType);

  @InheritConfiguration(name = "mapType")
  public abstract DtoType mapDtoType(Type type);
}
```

The generated `AttachmentMapperImpl` code is follows,

```
public class AttachmentMapperImpl implements AttachmentMapper {

    @Autowired

    private TypeMapper typeMapper;

    public AttachmentDto toDTO(Attachment attachment) {

    if ( attachment == null) {
        return null;
    }

    attachmentDTO.setType(typeMapper.mapDtoType(attachment.getType()));

    return attachmentDTO;
}
```

The issue is in the generated code, the `@Autowired typeMapper` is null. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `TypeMapper` does not use the spring `componentModel`. You would need to remove the `@Component` from the `TypeMapper` and use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` instead.

If you are using `AttachmentMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(AttachmentMapper.class);` to get the mapper then this is wrong as the `Mappers` factory should only be used with the `default` `componentModel`. If you are using Spring you should inject your mapper instead.

Comment: Thanks Filip. I was new to Mapstruct and spring in general and was struggling to understand what was going wrong. I have removed `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` and made it default and it worked. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Filip You said: _If you are using Spring you should inject your mapper instead._ I cannot use spring components outside the context. How about this: I need the same mapper in spring and outside spring. What is best practice to do?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use Spring outside the context? Are you using or not using Spring?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot in my project, but I have some classes which are **not** annotated with `@Component` or `@Bean`. I want to use mapper inside those classes. If I use the mapper with `componentModel = "spring"` I can **not** inject the mapper into those classes.

Comment: If that is the case, then I would not mix and match mappers. Especially if you want to have dependencies between mappers. Perhaps you should only use the default component model and use that everywhere.

Comment: @Filip I have the same issue as Robert, using Spring Boot, but want to use my Mappers in plain old JUnit tests, too, not firing up the entire Spring context for that. It works fine, but I'd rather avoid the warning...